# A demo example with JFreechart compile time error ?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have this code i'd like to compile , but it refuses to compile , clearly i'm missing a step.

I compile the code below as follow:

```
javac -cp .:jcommon-1.0.0.jar:jfreechart-1.0.1.jar App.java
```

The compile error basically:

cannot find org.jfree.data.xy.DefaultXYDataset
and precisely DefaultXYDataset.

```
import java.util.HashSet;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.data.xy.DefaultXYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;

    public class App {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Charts");

                    frame.setSize(600, 400);
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setVisible(true);

                    XYDataset ds = createDataset();
                    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("Test Chart",
                            "x", "y", ds, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true,
                            false);

                    ChartPanel cp = new ChartPanel(chart);

                    frame.getContentPane().add(cp);
                }
            });

        }

        private static XYDataset createDataset() {

            DefaultXYDataset ds = new DefaultXYDataset();

            double[][] data = { {0.1, 0.2, 0.3}, {1, 2, 3} };

            ds.addSeries("series1", data);

            return ds;
        }

    }
```

What am i missing here ?

Comment: if you're using windows , separator is `;` not `:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to use jfreechart-1.0.1.jar and DefaultXYDataset is present since 1.0.2.

You could download the correct version of jar and try again.

Courtesy: [javadoc for Class DefaultXYDataset](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/DefaultXYDataset.html)

Comment: @Sam Gomari: you could accept my answer if it heped you.